# JS SetInterval Speeds Up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, setinterval

Could someone explain why the following code behaves correctly for the first few repeats and then speeds up to manic pace? I searched and found that I should clearInterval before setInterval, but it made no difference.

```js
var begin = window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width = 600,
    height = canvas.height = 600;

  var stripWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1) + 5);
  for (i = 0; i <= (width / stripWidth); i++) {
    context.strokeRect(stripWidth * i, stripWidth * i, width - (2 * i * stripWidth), width - (2 * i * stripWidth));
  }
  clearInterval(begin);
  setInterval(begin, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `setInterval()`/`clearInterval()` wrong. `setInterval()` returns a timer-reference, this is the one you need to clear:

```
var timerRef;    // place in parent or global scope so it's accessible inside the function

var begin = window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = canvas.width = 600,
      height = canvas.height = 600;

  var stripWidth = Math.floor(Math.random()*(50-5+1)+5);
  for (i = 0; i<= (width / stripWidth); i++){
      context.strokeRect(stripWidth * i, stripWidth *i, 
                         width - (2 * i *  stripWidth), width - (2 * i * stripWidth));
  }
  clearInterval(timerRef);               // clear timer if any
  timerRef = setInterval(begin, 1000);   // store timerRef
};
```

`timerRef` may be `undefined`, `null` for `clearInterval()`

Comment: Thanks for that K3N. I'm curious about a couple of points though (as a newbie) - why do I need to define the variable timerRef before using it in the function? And why is setInterval called by assigning it to a variable? Are functions automatically called when assigned to variables or just this one? (My question probably shows some fairly basic conceptual confusion.)

Comment: @Robin timerRef is declared in the parent scope to be available inside the function (ie. able to reference it). If inside it would be a local var and only valid to the current call (ie. would be a new value each time). I rarely use functions assigned to vars myself, but setInterval is referencing a function just pointed to by the var. The ref. is then invoked by setInterval. This may sound confusing as well, but just experiment with these thing. Focus on isolated cases to understand everything about them (here: scopes, execution contexts, async). They'll all connect eventually. My 2 cents.